# Confused about javascript timeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function like this:

```
var a = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(2);
    }, 0);
    alert(1);
}

a();
```

the result is alert `1` first, then alert `2`

But I think, though `alert(2)` is in the `setTimeout`, but it executes immediately，because the delay is `0`

Why is the `alert(1)` executed first?

Comment: See Daniel Vandersluis' answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3580085/1317805

Comment: `setTimeout` have a minimum default delay, you can't do it 0

Comment: You should read this: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: @TamilVendhan Yeah that's a great reference. I also mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` has a default delay that will cause it to execute *after* `alert(1)` has executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't it to execute immediately just remove the setTimeout, you are getting `alert(1)` first because setTimeout has a minimum value see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647215/what-is-minimum-millisecond-value-of-settimeout). So when you set it to 0 it uses the minimum value depending on browser.

Answer (score 0):

As other also noted, setTimeout() has a minimum timeout of 4ms.

More importantly though, even if it had a real time-out of 0ms, it wouldn't fire first either. That's because Javascript is single-threaded (disregarding web-workers).

`alert(2)` fires last because anything set in setTimeout() will only fire after the current Javascript execution is done. In other words: setTimeout() actions are placed at the end of the execution stack.

So the current function execution will finish first (running the `alert(1)`) and only then the `alert(2)` gets executed.

That's also the reason that `setTimeout` only guarantees that the code within it is executed **after** the specified time, not at the **exact** time.

See http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ for a great overview.

Comment: Could the downvoter please revoke his vote? Or specify what's wrong with the answer? Because I'm pretty sure it's 100% correct.