Order of execution in NodeJS
I have the below code snippet in NodeJS.
console.log("START");

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log("setImmediate 1");
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("setTimeout 1");
}, 0);

Promise.resolve("hello").then((obj) => console.log("Promise 1"));

console.log("END");


Most of the time the output I get is as given below:
START
END
Promise 1
setTimeout 1
setImmediate 1

However in some cases I do get the below output:
START
END
Promise 1
setImmediate 1
setTimeout 1

Basically the execution order of the setTimeout and setImmediate are changing.
Can someone please make me understand the logic behind this?

Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647215/what-is-minimum-millisecond-value-of-settimeout   "these times are never 100% accurate"

Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580068/is-settimeout-with-no-delay-the-same-as-executing-the-function-instantly

Javascript is an asynchronous language.

Questions like this are largely irrelevant in real world programming for two reasons.  1) Real asynchronous operations (with promises) have an indeterminate time to being resolved (not immediately resolved as in your example).  2) If you really care which operation runs first, then you write your code to enforce that, you don't rely on the implementation differences in execution of these three functions.  Plus, there are probably hundreds of duplicates of questions like this.  You can go learn from those duplicates and should study them before posting your own.

setImmediate is essentially equivalent to setTimeout with a delay of zero. Per the Node.js documentation:

A setTimeout() callback with a 0ms delay is very similar to setImmediate(). The execution order will depend on various factors, but they will be both run in the next iteration of the event loop.

They are both asynchronous functions, albeit ones configured to execute with minimal delay (though not in the same event loop as they were called). As such, the specification makes no guarantees about their order of execution given that their conditions are met at the exact same time (when the next iteration of the event loop is reached). As far as Node is concerned, that's all you asked for.
If you need these instructions to execute in a defined order, your options include putting them in the same async function, or controlling the order of execution with promises.
